# How to take query string from the request URL passed as string in java and ignore the rest of the URL

Tags: java

The URL "localhost:9005/index.jsp?accountno=20&password=1234&username=abcd" is passed as a string to a Java file and from here I need to ignore till "?" and store the rest as a string in java.Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

Regex is a good option or you can also manipulate URLs using `java.net.URL` class:

```
URL url = new URL("http://" + "localhost:9005/index.jsp?accountno=20&password=1234&username=abcd");

System.out.println(url.getPath()); // prints: /index.jsp
System.out.println(url.getQuery()); // prints: accountno=20&password=1234&username=abcd
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex replacement would be one option here:

```
String url = "localhost:9005/index.jsp?accountno=20&password=1234&username=abcd";
String query = url.replaceAll("^.*?(?:\\?|$)", "");
System.out.println(query);
```

This prints:

```
accountno=20&password=1234&username=abcd
```

Answer (score 1):

### [String#substring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "localhost:9005/index.jsp?accountno=20&password=1234&username=abcd";
        String paramsStr = url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1);
        System.out.println(paramsStr);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
accountno=20&password=1234&username=abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()`

```
String url = "localhost:9005/index.jsp?accountno=20&password=1234&username=abcd";
String queryString = url.split("\\?")[1];
```

Comment: `?` is a reserved character for regex and is used to mark something optional. You need to escape it as `\\?` otherwise, you will be welcomed with `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException`.